# Sum/divide values from View results

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-view

I have 4 Views with columns and results like this:

```
 ___________________________________
| Account_no | Region_code | Total  |
|-----------------------------------
|123456789   | 123         | 321,34 |
|212234567   | 543         | 214    | 
|076948329   | 100         | 310    |
|093290432   | 320         | 1200,44|
|346574554   | 123         | 542,01 |
|___________________________________|
```

All these views has calculated column Total, but in order to get a complete result for each account in region I need to calculate Total again, with a formula like this : **View1.Total - View2.Total + View3.Total - View4.Total**.

Can somebody show me an example on how to achieve this in Oracle ?

Comment: Keyed by Account_no and Region_code?

Comment: @Stilgar, yes indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (simplified)?

```
SQL> with
  2  view1 (accno, total) as
  3    (select 1, 100 from dual union
  4     select 2, 200 from dual
  5    ),
  6  view2 (accno, total) as
  7    (select 1, 10 from dual union
  8     select 2, 30 from dual
  9    ),
 10  view3 (accno, total) as
 11    (select 1, 20 from dual union
 12     select 2, 40 from dual
 13    ),
 14  view4 (accno, total) as
 15    (select 1, 40 from dual union
 16     select 2, 30 from dual
 17    )
 18  --
 19  select v1.accno,
 20    (v1.total - v2.total + v3.total - v4.total) total_total
 21  from view1 v1 join view2 v2 on v1.accno = v2.accno
 22                join view3 v3 on v1.accno = v3.accno
 23                join view4 v4 on v1.accno = v4.accno;

     ACCNO TOTAL_TOTAL
---------- -----------
         1          70
         2         180

SQL>
```

Comment: what do these lines represent : "**select 1, 100 from dual union**" etc.

Comment: Your "account_no" and "total" values. As you didn't provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements, I was too lazy to type values you posted.

Comment: ok, I understand now. Unfortunally you suggestion doesn't work because It's based on that acoount_no allways exists in View1, but that's not the case....Some account_no are not in View1, but they are in other views.

Comment: How are we supposed to know that? Anyway: switch to **outer join** and see what happens.

Comment: I switched to full join and now It works, but I needed to handle all null values with NVL function. Thanks for example though !